# The theme constant statusBarScrollsUpBool doesn't work - how to make it work?

Tags: codenameone

IOS apps with scrollable areas usually scroll them up when the title bar is tapped.

There is a related theme constant `statusBarScrollsUpBool` but either way this does not work or only in the unlikely case one manages to tap the gap between the top of the screen and the title bar.

Now I am asking myself how to make it work.

`Form.getToolbar()` - then what? Obviously I cannot make it a lead component and there is no button.

I'd like to intercept a tap on the title bar the right way to be able to do the scrolling as it is provided by `Form.createStatusBar()`.

---

I tried that - which is almost good - but the title shrinks when tapped:

```
    Toolbar toolbar = getToolbar();
    Button buttonTitle = new Button(Command.create(getTitle(), null, actionListenerUp));
    buttonTitle.setUIID(toolbar.getTitleComponent().getUIID());
    toolbar.setTitleComponent(buttonTitle);
```

Comment: It will probably take forever for me to understand this UIID stuff. If I take the "Title" UIID why does it then behave different if the component is a button - shouldn't it just show the same behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTitleComponent` in `Toolbar` and stick in whatever you want including something like:

```
Button title = new Button("My Title", "Title");
```

Alternatively you can also try other options like maybe improving the code in `Form` or increasing the padding for the status bar to make it more touchable.

Comment: OK - I did use `Toolbar.setTitleComponent` and set its UUID to "Title". How can I make it not change its appearance when it is tapped?

Comment: You need to style the pressed/selected title and not just the unselected title. They aren't set by default for all themes

Comment: I mean if I tap the default title component it doesn't change appearance. And when I use Button and the same UUID it does

Comment: The default component isn't focusable so you never see selected/pressed states but once you replace it with a `Button` those states become applicable